# Form not being displayed in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am having a program.cs that is something like this :

```
namespace SumSwamp
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the program it executes without any errors But the form1 is not being displayed. Please tell me if am doing something wrong

[Here](http://pastebin.com/9zNHrHAJ) is my form class.

Comment: It depends on what's in `Form1` class...

Comment: Are you sure there are no errors? Look in the output window at the debug console.

Comment: please share your form1.cs code

Comment: @StuartGrassie Yeah there are no errors.

Comment: This is designer code. Please share code behind or Form1_Load.

Comment: @SiD http://pastebin.com/9zNHrHAJ Sorry for previosu link

Comment: @Raptor Added Form1_Load code

Comment: @Senthil Code link added.Please check

Comment: You know that you *can* insert code into the question, right?

Comment: @user3185653 no problem in your code, can you check with debugging mode and set breakpoint to run your programme

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I think its pretty big code to be added to post.

Comment: @Senthil I guess some loop is running infinite. Can you please help

Comment: @user3185653 s i think comment your code while loops one  by one so you will get which while loop problem

Comment: If you create windows application by default it should work. If you could see the same code in the Program.cs then your form1 will have some error.

Comment: @Senthil I am not able to get it..:(

Comment: @user3185653 y is there any problem

Comment: @Senthil I got the reason. But the loops while(Turn==0) and the While((CompSum < TotalSpaces) & (PlayerSum < TotalSpaces)) are running infinte

Comment: @Senthil But dont know why..Because i replace them with if instead of while and it executes

Comment: @user3185653 second while loop problem i think  while (Turn == 1)

Comment: in first while loop turn value not changed so the second while running infinite times While (Turn==1)

Answer (score 2):

From your posted code, your error lies in this piece;

```
public static Boolean WaitForRoll = true;
public static int Turn = 0;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
    while(Turn == 0) //always true
    {
        if (WaitForRoll==false) //always false
        {
            //never reached code
            DieTotal=DieLargeNum;
            Random rnd1 = new Random();
            DieLargeNum = rnd1.Next(1, 7);
            if (DieTotal>DieLargeNum)
            {
                Turn = 1;
                labelStatus.Text = "Player 1's Turn";
                WaitForRoll=true;
            }
            else
            {
                Turn = 2;
                labelStatus.Text = "Player 2's Turn";
                WaitForRoll = false;
            }
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

Look at it closely and you will find that your code never leaves the first `while` loop, and thus the constructor never comes to an end resulting in the `Form1` object never to be created.

Some tips;

- Rethink your design. You should not place this code in your constructor, but in methods.
- Read up on `while` loops. They are a pain if used incorrectly, which you did.

Comment: Yeah I know its going infinte along with one more while loop. Please help to correct it

Answer (score 1):

Your Form1 is not visible because there is an infinite loop in your code. Please check the following code it goes infinite.

```
while ((CompSum < TotalSpaces) & (PlayerSum < TotalSpaces))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know its going infinte.Please help to correct it

Comment: Becasue the `Turn=0` it is neither going inside `while (Turn == 1)` or `while (Turn == 2)`. That's why value of `CompSum` is never changed and it stays in while loop. You need to rethink your design. Code in constructor is not a good choice.